# Push without Pull from Couchbase Lite

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm collecting some analytic data on my client device which does not require any initial data from the server database.

Is it possible to start with an empty database, add some analytic documents and then when I'm ready use push replication to add those documents to my server database with the sync gate?

I'm going to have an analytics channel but I don't want to pull EVERYTHING from that channel into my client database since it doesn't care about what's there already, it only wants to add to it.

I would be asking this question on the Couchbase forums but it is currently down.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, push and pull replications are entirely separate so as long as you do not create a pull replication you won't receive any data from sync gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following API from `CBLDatabase` to upload data to server.'

```c
/** Creates a replication that will 'push' this database to a remote database at the given URL.
    This always creates a new replication, even if there is already one to the given URL.
    You must call -start on the replication to start it. */
- (CBLReplication*) createPushReplication: (NSURL*)url;
```

Here's an example how you can setup push replication.

```c
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://example.com/mydatabase/"];
CBLReplication *push = [database createPushReplication: url];
push.continuous = YES; // NO for One-shot replication
//After authenticating and adding progress observers here, call -start
[push start];
```

You can set-up pull replication(if needed) in similar way by using `-createPullReplication:`. Read more from docs over here - [Replication](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html).